# Как обрезать строку js?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.` 
Ее длина может быть разной. Как обрезать строку так, чтоб остались лишь первые 10 символов?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно использовать [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
"Lorem ipsum...".substring(0, 10);
```

Или [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
"Lorem ipsum...".substr(0, 10);
```

Или [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
"Lorem ipsum...".slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `slice`
Подробнее тут  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

```js
var string ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
console.log(string.slice(0, 10))
```